# ProGuard modifies (increases size) skipped classes

Tags: java, jar, proguard, obfuscation, executable-jar

I'm obfuscating an executable jar using ProGuard version 5.3.3.

My jar contains other libraries which I do not want to obfuscate or optimize.

This is my ProGuard config:

```
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\rt.jar'

-injars myjar-debug.jar
-outjars myjar-release.jar

-skipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontoptimize
-dontshrink
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-keeppackagenames org.**
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod
-ignorewarnings

-keep class org.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class org.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.**

-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

The obfuscation works perfectly fine and there are no errors in executing the jar. However, if I compare the original jar and the obfuscated jar, I can see that ProGuard has modified classes within package `org.**`. Most of the class files size is more than the original size.

[image: Original Jar(Left) VS Obfuscated Jar(Right)]

I don't want ProGuard to modify these files at all. How can I completely exclude this package so that the binary of the class files in `org.**` are exactly same?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tweak your jar building process, and obfuscate first then make executable jar.

I am not sure if you are using maven/gradle however this will make your life easy compared to using command line

Comment: does it matter how the jar is created?

Comment: for some extent yes, in your case if you obfuscate first before creating a fat(executable) jar, which means your jar is only containing the source code, subsequently the process of creating executable jar will bundle dependencies.